# Count ReferenceId exists in schemaId other -sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

Table1 :

```
 ReferenceId    |Name
    00000001    | Terminal A
    00000222    | Terminal 1
    00000223    | Terminal 11
    00000023    | Terminal 2
    00000030    | Terminal B
    00000031    | Terminal B1
    00000032    | Terminal B2
    00000033    | Terminal 4
    00000034    | Terminal D
    00000035    | Terminal E
    00000036    | Terminal F
    00000037    | Terminal B3
```

Table2:

```
 SchemaId   | ReferenceId 
    1           | 00000001-00000023,00000222,00000035-00000036
    2           | 00000007-00000023,00000223,00000036-00000037
    3           | 00000001-00000030,00000222-00000223
    4           | 00000001-99999999
```

Example : 
Schmema1 (Count ReferenceId exists in table1 and SchemaId Other)

```
ReferenceId | Schmema   | Isdisplay     | Note
00000001    |3,4        | 1
00000002    |0          | 0         | Not exists in table1
...
00000023    |2,3,4      | 1
00000222    |3,4        | 1
00000035    |4          | 1
00000036    |2,4        | 1
=> **total** 5
```

Example : Schmema2

```
 ReferenceId | Schmema      | Isdisplay     | Note
    00000007    |0          | 0             | Not exists in table1
    ...
    00000023    |1,3,4      | 1         
    00000223    |3,4        | 1
    00000036    |1,4        | 1         
    00000037    |4          | 1     
    => **total** 4
```

Example : Schmema3

```
ReferenceId | Schmema   | Isdisplay     | Note
00000001    |1,4        | 1     
00000023    |1,2,4      | 1
00000030    |4          | 1         
00000222    |1,4        | 1         
00000223    |2,4        | 1
=> **total** 5
```

Example : Schmema4

```
 ReferenceId | Schmema      | Isdisplay     | Note
    00000001    |1,3        | 1     
    00000002    |0          | 0
    00000003    |0          | 0
    ...
    00000023    |1,2,3      | 1
    00000024    |0          | 0
    ...
    00000030    |3          | 1
    00000031    |0          | 0         | Not exists in schmemaId other
    00000032    |0          | 0         | Not exists in schmemaId other
    ...
    00000035    |1          | 1         
    00000036    |1,2        | 1
    00000037    |2          | 1         
    ...
    00000222    |1,3        | 1         
    00000223    |2,3        | 1
    => **total** 8
```

The result is expected of me:

```
SchemaId    | ReferenceId           |CountReferenceIdExistsSchemaIdOther
1           | 00000001-00000023,00000222,00000035-00000036      |5
2           | 00000007-00000023,00000223,00000036-00000037      |4
3           | 00000001-00000023,00000222-00000223               |5
4           | 00000001-99999999                                 |8
```

How to get the results expected? Please, you help me.

Comment: What issue you are having ? & what u have tried so far ?

Comment: In schema 1 for ReferenceId 00000001 why you have considered only schemas 3 & 4 why not 1? Same for ReferenceID 00000007 in schema 2.